# EF6 - Annotation to allow empty string but not allow null

Tags: entity-framework

In EF6, is there a annotation that will allow empty string but not allow null?

I've tried [Required].  But this annotation does not allow empty string or null.

```
[Required]
[MaxLength(80)]
public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is the reason behind it?

Comment: In most case, I see little to no reason to put null value in database.  Checking for empty string is just as good as checking for null.  In most case, I don't see a reason to check for both.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like I just need to add the (AllowEmptyStrings = true) option to the [Required] annotation.

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
[MaxLength(80)]
public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
```